# Is it guaranteed that SDL_RenderCopy will not be anti-aliased?

Tags: antialiasing, sdl-2

The SDL documentation for SDL_RenderCopy says that the texture will be stretched, but I can find absolutely no information about **how** the stretching will be done.

My experiments on Linux show that stretching is not anti-aliased. Can I rely on this? Will it behave the same way on other platforms? Will it not change in future versions?

Searching for *anti-aliasing* in SDL Wiki yields only 1 result, and it refers to the OpenGL configuration; the Wiki seems to be silent on how the stretching of textures is done. I’m writing a pixel-art game that won’t look good if anti-aliasing is applied, so I’d like to make sure it will never be anti-aliased.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is guaranteed that by default SDL2 uses the nearest pixel stretching. You need to explicitly enable any other format by hinting it (explained at http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY).

Good look at your game.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sorry, I didn't accept it earlier because I was away from my main computer and didn't have the password with me.